# extract a string from the given index of another string java

Tags: java, android, json

I have retrieved a string in JSON format(string name is "weatherJsonStr"), the string looks like this :

```
                 "... day": 28.09, "min": 2.73,"max": 28.09, ..."
```

I want to extract the value in front of max i.e 28.09 and store it in a variable.
I have found the index where "max" starts, using the following code:

```
 String max="max";
 int index=weatherJsonStr.indexOf(max);
```

I am a little lost after that. I did end up doing :

```
int index=weatherJsonStr.indexOf(max)+5;//to get to the starting index of 28.09
```

But I can't figure of how to extract the numeric value after that.

Comment: Why are not using [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject(org.json.JSONTokener)) and than `getString("max")`?

Comment: Or may be `getDouble("max")` ?

Comment: Oh! Had not looked up JSONObject thanks for the hint